# Can any security mechanism be used with any binding in WCF?

Tags: c#, wcf, security

I am starting out with **WCF with the Wrox Professionsl Book on WCF with .NET**. In the chapter on WCF security the `Message` and `Transport` security mechanisms are listed.

Also it is mentioned that netTCPBinding works with Transport level security. Does this mean that this is the default security mode but it can be changed based on the requirements.

In general the question is **Can any security mechanism be used with any binding in WCF?**

Kindly excuse me if this is a very fundamental question.

Comment: I think the book you mentioned lists quite clearly which combinations are valid. Anyway, Microsoft lists them as well : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731172%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: A Good source with some fundamental answers - [Chapter 4: WCF Security Fundamentals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650862.aspx) and [Chapter 7: Message and Transport Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648863.aspx)